# How to make google tv to autostart an app and restart it at a set time

Tags: android, google-tv

I am working on a project that requires that whenever the google tv box powers on, it should auto start the app; and also, while it's running, it should restart the app at a certain time of the day.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver for the "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" intent to be informed when the box boots up.

The AlarmManager allows you to invoke BroadcastReceivers based on various time intervals.